# Getting wrong results: Time-zone issue when hitting api from AngularJS and querying for result from firebase using NodeJS

Tags: node.js, angularjs, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

I have wrong result returned when queried with date-range.

I am using DateRangePicker jQuery for selecting date range and time range.

Then I hit my api and send my date/Moment js object to my node js api on which I query firestore for docs added on a specific date range!

This is my code:

```
api.get('/getDoc', async function(req,res){

var start = new Date(req.query.fromDateData);
var end = new Date(req.query.toDateData);

ref = db.collection(req.query.brand);


if(! req.query.alert==''){
    ref = ref.where(req.query.alert,'==',true);
}

ref= ref.where('firebaseAddDate', '>', start).where('firebaseAddDate', '<', end).orderBy('firebaseAddDate', 'desc');

ref = await ref.limit(50).get();
```

if i enter this date:

```
fromDateData: 'Mon Nov 29 2021 00:00:00 GMT 0500 (Pakistan Standard Time)',
toDateData: 'Mon Nov 29 2021 23:59:00 GMT 0500 (Pakistan Standard Time)',
```

i get results from

```
Mon Nov 29 2021 04:xx:00
Tue Nov 30 2021 04:xx:00
```

I am getting 5 hours ahead results from the defined time. idk how to deal with this and I have tried changing offsets and using utc and using epoch time. but unable to handle.
this is the variable I am querying about:
[image]

Comment: Your question isn't really clear but you should note that date/times in Firestore are stored in UTC. Maybe this will help you figure out your issue

Comment: @NoCommandLine let me check this once again with utc and i'll follow up!

Answer (score 1):

I'll answer my question which might help someone with my use case:-

when using jQuery Date-Range-Picker with time-range like this

[image]

remember to set time zones like this:

```
$('#dateRange').daterangepicker({
    timePicker: true,
    timePicker24Hour: true,
    startDate: moment().subtract(1,'days').startOf("day").utc(),
    endDate:moment().endOf("day").utc(),
    opens: 'left',
    showTimezone: true, 
    timezone: "+0000"
}, async function(start, end, label) {
    $scope.fromDateData= await start.utc(); //.format('DD-MM-YYYY H:mm');
    $scope.toDateData= await end.utc(); //.format('DD-MM-YYYY H:mm');
    console.log(`A new date selection was made: ${$scope.fromDateData} to ${$scope.toDateData}`);
    $scope.ff=true;
    $scope.$digest();
});
```

now when querying firebase firestore in NodeJS for date range. make sure your object is saved in epoch time format. you can do that with this method:

```
var current_date_utc =  Date.UTC(current_date.getUTCFullYear(), current_date.getUTCMonth(), current_date.getUTCDate(),
    current_date.getUTCHours(), current_date.getUTCMinutes(), current_date.getUTCSeconds()); //will store in format of numbers

const ref = await db.collection('saud').doc().set({
    'firebaseAddDate': current_date_utc,
});
```

now if your date is stored in epoch time format the way to query docs using date range. you will use this method:

```
//api is hit
api.get('/getDoc', async function(req,res){
//api body
console.log(req.query);
var start = new Date(req.query.fromDateData);
var end = new Date(req.query.toDateData);

//setting utc date format that is same as epoch time format
var start_utc =  Date.UTC(start.getUTCFullYear(), start.getUTCMonth(), start.getUTCDate(),
    start.getUTCHours(), start.getUTCMinutes(), start.getUTCSeconds());
var end_utc =  Date.UTC(end.getUTCFullYear(), end.getUTCMonth(), end.getUTCDate(),
    end.getUTCHours(), end.getUTCMinutes(), end.getUTCSeconds());

ref = db.collection('saud');

if(! req.query.alert==''){
    ref = ref.where(req.query.alert,'==',true);
}

ref= ref.where('firebaseAddDate', '>', start_utc).where('firebaseAddDate', '<', end_utc).orderBy('firebaseAddDate', 'desc');

ref = await ref.limit(50).get();
```